# How to make execution window in GNAT GPS do text I/O in the correct order for Ada?

Tags: gps, ide, ada

I'm running GPS on Windows 8.1.
Version info:
GPS 6.0.1 (20140113) hosted on i686-pc-mingw32
GNAT GPL 2014 (20140331)

The output is different when I run my program in the IDE, vs when I run it from the Windows command line.

In the GPS execution window, it doesn't display the prompt until I type something, like this:

> **Bob**
>   What is your name? Hi there, Bob!

In the command line the same program works properly, like this:

> What is your name? **Bob**
>   Hi there, Bob!

How do I make the GPS execution window work properly?

Here is my code (Demo_Execution_Window.adb):

```
with Ada.Text_IO,
     Ada.Strings.Unbounded,
     Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Text_IO;

use Ada.Text_IO,
    Ada.Strings.Unbounded,
    Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Text_IO;

procedure Demo_Execution_Window is
   Input : Unbounded_String;
begin
   New_Line;
   Put("What is your name? ");
   Get_Line(Input);
   Put("Hi there, "); Put(Input); Put_Line("!");
end Demo_Execution_Window;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the GPS version and a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess (I don't use GPS myself) is that your problem simply is that GPS behaves differently from your terminal window.  It appears that GPS buffers the output until the program sends a line-feed.  If my analysis is correct, you have two options:

1. Add a line-feed after the question (i.e. change `Put` to `Put_Line`).
2. Fix the GPS output processing, so it doesn't wait for a line-feed before displaying the output from a program.

And of course also the third option, to accept that things look slightly different inside your IDE compared to real life use.